How do I save data in express.js and show it in the webpage without a database?
So I am doing this project and I have to make a website in which i can create blog text posts, and then show those posts to access what i posted. I am using html css js node.js, ejs and express.js, I cant use a database so how should I do this?
Currently I have made a website and i can show the inputs after the post button is pressed, but when i refresh the page, data goes away and i have to do it over again.
Is there any logic I can use to make this happen?
`app.post("/submit", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const articles = req.body.post
    res.render("index.ejs", {data: articles});

});`


You could always save it to a file...

@Mureinik - so, you'd save it in a structured set of data held in a computer? :p

Why can't you use a database? You can use a file, but it's a poor design for large amounts of data. This is exactly what databases are for.

@Barmar because its like a small project thing (I'm a noob) and they haven't taught databases yet and the assignment is to make a blog web app and store the posts without database so the post maker can access it.

Store data in storage.json maybe? Save the blog posts to this file on the server then read from this file whenever you need to display the posts. You can use the fs module to read and write files.
Also try to remove type="submit" on Submit button and try to saving to this file storage.json on click event of that Submit button.You can also try onClick()
